# Representation of linear transformation of matrices

Tags: matrices, reference-request, linear-transformations

The transformation of any matrix $A$ that switches two rows (or two columns) in $A$ can be represented as a product between $A$ and a transformation matrix.

**The question is**: what kind of linear transformations between (linear spaces of) matrices can be represented in a similar way? In particular, what is the answer for the transposition of matrices and for the rotation of matrices ($90$ degrees counterclockwise)?

Also, any good reference on the subject is welcomed.

[I assume it has to do with the dimension of the kernel of the transformation... but this a way of saying that I clearly need help, since my linear algebra is a little rusty]

Answer (score 1):

The corollary on page 20 of [*Linear Algebra* by Hoffman and Kunze](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit) partially answers your first question: Let $A$ and $B$ be $m \times n$ matrices over a field $\Bbb F.$ Then $B$ is row-equivalent to $A$ if and only if $B = PA,$ where $P$ is a product of $m \times m$ elementary matrices.  We get the full answer if we allow some rows of $P$ to be zero: The kinds of linear transformations that can be represented by left multiplication are those such that $B$ is row-equivalent to $A$ but possibly with some zero rows in $B.$ Right multiplication gives an analogous result for columns.

Transposed matrices are not necessarily row-equivalent, so no such matrix exists (but see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1143642).

Rotation of a vector counterclockwise in $\Bbb R^2$ by the angle $\theta$ is given by left multiplication by
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos \theta & \sin \theta\\
-\sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}.$$
For $\theta = 90^\circ,$ the matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1\\
-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

In $\Bbb R^3,$ see equation (20) in ["Three-Dimensional Rotation Matrices."](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph216/rotation_12.pdf#page=5)