# matrix differentiation 2

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Define matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times k}$, matrix $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times k}$, and vector $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{C}^{k \times 1}$.
Also, assume that $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are independent of $\mathbf{B}$. What is the derivative of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}\mathbf{c}$ respect to $\mathbf{B}$.

Comment: I've doubts this is differentiable, i.e. the main question is the differntiability of Transpose, which doesn't look to me a continuous function for a first glance.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\C{\mathbf C}\def\M#1#2{\operatorname{Mat}_{#1,#2}(\C)}$Denote by $f \colon \M mk \to \C^n$ the function in question, that is 
$$ f(B) = AB^tBc $$
We have for any $B, H \in \M mk$ that
\begin{align*}
  f(B+H) - f(B) &= A(B^t + H^t)(B + H)c - AB^tBc\\
                &= AH^tBc + AB^tHc + AH^tHc
\end{align*}
Now, note that $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}$by submultiplikativity and continuity of $B \mapsto B^t$, we have
$$ \norm{AH^tHc} \le \norm A \norm H^2 \norm c = o(\norm H), \qquad H \to 0$$
That is, the (Frechet) derivative of $f$ at $B$ is the function 
$$ f'(B) \colon \M mk \to \C^n, \qquad H \mapsto AH^t Bc + AB^tHc $$

Comment: can you please explain or provide a reference to why transpose is continuous and differentiable function?

Comment: The transpose is a linear map $(-)^t \colon \M nm \to \M mn$, *every* linear map $T$ between finite dimensional vector spaces is continuous (and hence differentiable with $T'(x) = T$, all $x$), see for example here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous ... and as far as it matters for $f$, we've shown it above.

Comment: thanks, note in the second equation, last term is fixed should be $AH^tHc$

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Thx, corrected.

Comment: ahem.... the transpose is not a linear map   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143614/is-matrix-transpose-a-linear-transformation

Comment: The transpose is linear for sure, as $(\mu A+\lambda B)^t = \mu A^t + \lambda B^t$, which is the definition of being linear.

Comment: "linear map" and linear is not the same thing, linear map would mean that there is a matrix $M$ such that for all matrix $A$ , $A^T=MA$

Comment: also the link you have provided states the continuity of a linear map, but not the differentiability.