# Are all isomorphisms between matrices of the form $ T(A)=UA$ for some matrix $U$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U\in M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})$ be an invertible matrix and T:$ M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})\mapsto M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})$ is a linear map defined by T(A)=UA.

My question is, are all isomorphisms between $M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})$ and $M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})$ of this form? Say, if S:$M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})\mapsto M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})$ is an isomorphism, does an invertible matrix M$\in M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})$ exist such that S(A)=MA.   $\forall A\in M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: How would you represent $R(A) = AU$ in the form above? To give a more concrete example: How would you represent a column permutation in this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $A \mapsto A^T$ is not of this form.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143614/is-matrix-transpose-a-linear-transformation.

Comment: Yes! It was easy to prove that it is also bijective and thus an isomorphism.