# Fractional matrix transpose operator

Tags: matrices, functional-equations, transpose

I can define one version of a *fractional-transpose* quite easily by interpolation between the exchanged elements:

- Take $\mathbf{U}(\mathbf{A})$ as the upper triangle of $\mathbf{A}$ excluding the main diagonal of $\mathbf{A}$.
- Take $\mathbf{L}(\mathbf{A})$ as the lower triangle of $\mathbf{A}$ excluding the main diagonal of $\mathbf{A}$.
- Let $\mathbf{D}$ be the matrix with the same diagonal of $\mathbf{A}$ and zeros elsewhere.

Then I can form:
$$T_\alpha(\mathbf{A}) = \mathbf{D}+\left[\alpha\mathbf{U}(\mathbf{A}^\top)+(1-\alpha)\mathbf{U}(\mathbf{A})\right]+\left[\alpha\mathbf{L}(\mathbf{A}^\top)+(1-\alpha)\mathbf{L}(\mathbf{A})\right]$$

Then we have $T_0(\mathbf{A})=\mathbf{A}$ and $T_1(\mathbf{A})=\mathbf{A}^\top$.

However, this doesn't have the nice properties that $T_{1-\alpha}(T_{\alpha}(\mathbf{A}))=\mathbf{A}^\top$ and $T_{1-\alpha}(T_{\alpha}(\mathbf{A}^\top))=\mathbf{A}$.

Can you help me come up with an operation $T_\alpha$ that can be repeatedly applied like this to get the transpose?

Comment: I had a vague idea about finding a rotation so that $\mathbf{R}\cdot\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{A})=\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{A^\top})$ but that's about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider the space of $2\times2$ matrices. As noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1143622/64206), the transposition operator acting on the elements of such space can be represented by a $4\times4$ matrix. In particular, if we take the $2\times2$ matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix},$$

then, after flattening it into a column vector

$$A'=\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b\\ c\\ d\end{pmatrix},$$

we can represent the transposition operator with the following [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix):

$$T_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

If you now take [square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix) of this matrix, you'll get the half-transposition operator representation:

$$T_{1/2}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0& \frac12+\frac i2 & \frac12-\frac i2 &0\\
0& \frac12-\frac i2 & \frac12+\frac i2 &0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Similarly you can take other powers of $T_1$ to get the general matrix $T_\alpha$. Also similarly, you can extend this to higher-dimensional $A$-matrices.

Comment: Thanks very much. This should be easy to construct in Mathematica now. Are you aware of any applications of the fractional transpose? It would be interesting to see if it's more than just a curiosity.

Comment: @flinty no, I'm not aware of any applications. I haven't even seen any publications about it (there might be a lot, I just haven't searched): I've just devised this method by myself.

Comment: Well in any case, it's pretty cool - especially since the operator involves complex entries.

Comment: This has some properties: if we denote the full transpose by $A^\top$ and the fractional transpose by  $A^{\top(\alpha)}$, then in general we appear to have $A^\top+A=A^{\top(\alpha+1)}+A^{\top(\alpha)}$, and also $A^{\top(\alpha)}-A$ is anti-symmetric. Unsurprisingly $A^{\top(\alpha)}=A$ when $A$ is symmetric. We also have $(A+B)^{\top(\alpha)}=A^{\top(\alpha)}+B^{\top(\alpha)}$, but we do not have the analogue for the transpose of matrix products for general $\alpha$. The determinant  $\det(A^{\top(\alpha)})$ is wave-like as we vary $\alpha$, but that's about all I can say.