# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a linear transformation that transposes a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

a) Consider the transformation $T$ in the space $M^{2\times2}$ of $2\times2$ matrices, $T(A)=A^{\top}$. Find all its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Is it possible to diagonalize this transformation?

b) Can you do the same problem but in the space of $n\times n$ matrices?

Since all linear transformation can be represented as a matrix, there should be a matrix that multiplies a $2 \times 2$ matrix that turns it into its transpose. But based on what I've read so far, there is no such matrix that exist. I might be misunderstanding this question, but if we can't find this matrix, how are we suppose to find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Note that the space of $2\times2$ matrices is $4$-dimensional, so the matrix representing a transformation in the space of $2\times2$ matrices will be $4\times4$

Comment: oh yes . a 4 by 4 matrix would be possible. I assumed it had to be a 2 by 2 matrix which would be impossible

Comment: You've just got to think about how you would represent a $2\times2$ matrix as a column vector; I guess it would live in $\mathbb R^4$. Since the transpose swaps two elements in a matrix, the corresponding transformation of $\mathbb R^4$ would do the same. The $4\times4$ matrices that do this are called [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix). If you study those, I think you'll find your answer.

Comment: Even if you couldn't find the matrix, you could still find all the solutions of $A^t=\lambda A$, couldn't you, William?

Comment: is the transformation that transpose matrix actually a liner map? there are many threads here saying it is not linear?

Comment: If $(A+B)^t=A^t+B^t$, and $(cA)^t=cA^t$, then it's linear, right, William?

Comment: @GerryMyerson is the transpose transformation for a specific matrix linear? I believe the operation that transposes all matrix is not a linear transformation, however it is linear if we fix a specific matrix to transpose. But even without any matrix, we know the diagonals are unchanged so the diagonal entries will be the eigenvalues

Comment: @GerryMyerson https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143614/is-matrix-transpose-a-linear-transformation  The top answer here is saying that matrix transpose is not a linear transformation

Comment: What is the eigenvalue for $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$ under the transpose transformation?

Comment: You have a map T from a vector space to itself. You have a definition of what it means for that map to be linear. You apply that definition to that map, using what you know about the transpose. Then, you tell me whether or not it's a linear transformation on that vector space.

Comment: You have only read the first half of that top answer. Please go back and read the second half, William.

Comment: So, William, where do we stand now?

Comment: @GerryMyerson this problem is solved now. I set T^2=I which means the only eigenvalues are -1,1 where 1 corresponds to the symmetric matrices, so its multiplicity is n and -1 is for the anti symmetric matrices with multiplicity n(n-1) Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you're undercounting the symmetric matrices (and overcounting the antisymmetric). But let me encourage you to write up what you have found, and to post it as an answer.

Comment: For example, the symmetric $2\times2$ matrices form a vector space of dimension three, the antisymmetric, one, whereas your formulas give two for both.

Answer (score 2):

For solving this problem, my suggestion is that you use isomorphism first. Since the domain is $M^{2\times2}$, the basis should be $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, which I named as $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ orderly.

Then we hope $Tv_1=v_1,\;Tv_2=v_3,\;Tv_3=v_2,\;Tv_4=v_4$.

Thus $[T]_{\mathcal{B}} =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\det([T]_\mathcal{B}-\lambda I)=(\lambda-1)^3(\lambda+1)$.

Then compute the $\text{Ker}(T-\lambda I)$.

For $\lambda = 1$, $\text{Ker}(T-I)=\text{span}\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$.

For $\lambda = -1$, $\text{Ker}(T+I)=\text{span}\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$.

By written in this form, you can diagonalize it.

When problem goes to $M^{n\times n}$, you just write a basis in the same way and abstract it to a basis $\mathcal{B}={v_1,\dots,v_{n^2}}$, better in a relatively symmetric way (i.e. swap $v_i$ and $v_{n^2+1-i}$) so that your $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$. In this way, you can compute the characteristic polynomial easier.

Answer (score 1):

When you're treating matrices as *objects* in a vector space, instead of as representations of a transformation, then it's often useful to think of them as vectors with components.

A 2x2 matrix has four components, a 3x3 matrix has 9 components, a 4x4 matrix has 16 components, and so on.

Every 2x2 matrix can be written uniquely as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix} = a\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 &0 \end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 &0 \end{bmatrix} + c\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 &0 \end{bmatrix}+d\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$$

In other words, these four matrices on the right hand side form a basis for the space.

---

Because we're treating these matrices as objects in a vector space, you are free to write them *as vectors* if you like.

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix} \leadsto \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\\ c\\d\end{bmatrix}$$

Written in this form, transposition is the transformation:

$$T : \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\\ c\\d\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}a \\ c\\ b\\d\end{bmatrix}$$

which you can write in matrix form as:

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1& 0 & 0\\ 0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}_T\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\\ c\\d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a \\ c\\ b\\d\end{bmatrix}$$

and you can do the rest.

---

Of course, you can also get some intuition about transposition using intuition about eigenvectors, without relying on specific components.

If a linear transformation scales an object by a factor of $\lambda\neq 0$, then that object is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. (As a special case, if a linear transformation has no effect on an object, it's an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.)

Let's exclude the zero matrix from consideration in everything that follows.  There are three kinds of matrices that are unaffected by transposition $T$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & b\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}0 & c\\ c & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

As a result, these are eigenvectors of $T$, and they all have eigenvalue 1.  The linear combinations of these matrices form a three dimensional space of matrices that  are all eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & c \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\qquad \forall a, b, c$$